# Схема предложения и вид подчинения

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить схему предложения и определить вид подчинения:

*Нехлюдов был так занят разными удовольствиями, что хотя несколько раз на день заезжала нам, но ни разу не поговорил со мной.*

Спасибо.

Comment: Предложение из упражнения, но в тексте Л. Н. Толстого не получается его найти. Переделка? Но почему стилистика некорректная? Повтор слова "раз", например. Возможное редактирование: Нехлюдов был настолько занят разными удовольствиями, что хотя по нескольку на день заезжал к нам, так и не поговорил со мной.  Впрочем, для упражнения СОЙДЕТ, но жаль, что оно составлено по Толстому.

Answer (score 1):

1. *Нехлюдов был **так** занят разными удовольствиями, **что хотя** несколько раз на день заезжал к нам, **но** ни разу не поговорил со мной.*

Запятая на стыке союзов не ставится,так как ***ХОТЯ...НО*** двойной союз.

2. **Структура** предложения: *Нехлюдов был **так** занят разными удовольствиями, **что** ни разу не поговорил со мной, **хотя** несколько раз на день заезжал к нам.*

Это ***СПП*** с **последовательным** подчинением придаточных: **главное** предложение — придаточное **образа действия и следствия**  (*так...что*) — **уступительное** придаточное (*хотя...но*).

Инверсия придаточного уступительного предложения. Оба придаточных неполные, пропущено местоимение ***он***.

Местоименно-союзная связь ***ТАК...ЧТО.*** Двойной подчинительный союз ***ХОТЯ...НО***.

3. **Схема предложения:**

[ — = так], (что (хотя =), но =).